# SQL Server On Premise to Azure Data Warehouse: Copy Multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2016, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

We want to copy 1000+ tables from SQL Server on premise to an Azure Data Warehouse.
Does Azure Data factory have a quick operation to conduct both initial and Daily incremental loading from SQL Server OLTP to Azure Data warehouse? The loading can be a quick 1:1 copy, no transformations needed. We will conduct transformation and denormalization on the Azure DW staging side (roundrobin tables).

We are refraining from SSIS, since the development time is very high to create 1000 packages.

Does Azure Data Warehouse allow:

1. Replication from SQL Server on premise to Azure Data Warehouse?
2. Log Shipping from SQL Server on premise to Azure Data Warehouse?
3. AlwaysOn AG from SQL Server on premise to Azure Data Warehouse?
4. Backup (Full, Differential, Transaction log) from SQL Server on premise to Azure Data Warehouse?
5. Azure Data Factory from SQL Server on premise to Azure Data Warehouse?

Seeking straight copies, with focus on quick and very low development time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server

Comment: why was this question voted -1? want to undertand, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Data Factory offers the following benefits for loading data into Azure SQL Data Warehouse:

**1.** Easy to set up: An intuitive 5-step wizard with no scripting required.
Rich data store support: Built-in support for a rich set of on-premises and cloud-based data stores. For a detailed list, see the table of Supported data stores.

**2.** Secure and compliant: Data is transferred over HTTPS or ExpressRoute. The global service presence ensures that your data never leaves the geographical boundary.

**3.** Unparalleled performance by using PolyBase: Polybase is the most efficient way to move data into Azure SQL Data Warehouse. Use the staging blob feature to achieve high load speeds from all types of data stores, including Azure Blob storage and Data Lake Store. (Polybase supports Azure Blob storage and Azure Data Lake Store by default.) For details, see Copy activity performance.

You don't want to use SSIS, and i think you also found that Microsoft provides the tutorial about [Load data into Azure SQL Data Warehouse by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/load-azure-sql-data-warehouse).

Maybe this couldn't answer your five questions directly, still hope this can helps you.

Comment: thanks, however was looking into more direct answers